# Regex options for std::regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, multiline, ecmascript-5

I was looking for a way of switching between multiline/singleline regex so that the $ means the end of input/the end of line. I've looked through different guides and they point to some OPTIONS for this. However, I can't find any such options for std::basic_regex in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex/. I've came across a recommendation to use (s) (or something like) in the beginnning of a regex but it causes an exception.

Are there a list of any additional options which can be passed to a std::regex in addition to flags that can be passed to basic_regex constructor?

Comment: Multiline flag is [an open issue](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2343). [There are flags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_flag_type) you can pass to `regex_match` et al, but they are of little help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `(?s)` flag is not yet supported by C++.

But you can still do a multiline regex match.

To match everything on a single line use: `.*`

To match everything on multiple lines use: `(?:.|\n)*`